# android material button cannot remove round corners

Tags: android, material-design, android-button, material-components-android

I need to remove round corners of all buttons in app and use flat background. preferably a color.

This is my style:

```
<style name="Component.MyTheme.Button" parent="Widget.MaterialComponents.Button.TextButton">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/white_50</item>
    <item name="backgroundTint">@color/black</item>
    <item name="cornerRadius">@null</item>
</style>
```

and this is how I apply it in my theme.

```
<item name="materialButtonStyle">@style/Component.MyTheme.Button</item>
```

I want to change this

[image]

to this

[image]

EDIT : Ignore white bars at either ends of 2nd image.

Comment: did you tried giving 0 as the value to the cornerRadius

Comment: hi. both @Pritish Deshpande and your solution works. Thanks.

Answer (score 10):

set corner radius attibute to 0dp.

```
app:cornerRadius="0dp"
```

Like below code

```
<com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
            android:id="@+id/button_filter_apply"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/apply"
            android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
            android:textAllCaps="true"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            app:backgroundTint="@color/clear_blue"
            app:cornerRadius="0dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent" />
```

Button looks like

[image]

EDIT : Ignore black bars on both side of the image

Answer (score 2):

Just use:

```
<style name="Component.MyTheme.Button" parent="Widget.MaterialComponents.Button.TextButton">
    ...
    <item name="cornerRadius">0dp</item>
</style>
```

or

```
<style name="MyButton" parent="Widget.MaterialComponents.Button.TextButton">
    ...
    <item name="shapeAppearanceOverlay">@style/shapeAppearanceOverlay_noCorner</item>
</style>

<style name="shapeAppearanceOverlay_noCorner" parent="">
    <item name="cornerSize">0dp</item>
</style>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

As you said you would like to add themes to your button.
Can you please try adding `0.1` to your corner radius?

Comment: because themes allow a consistent way of handling look of the app.

Comment: @ChandanPednekar Edited answer please see.

Comment: your edit is what @vikas kumar suggested. but I found ShapeAppearance to be a subtly nice way of overriding parameters.

Comment: No worries.
Happy coding!!